# Is it necessary to create every character using mirror modifier with limited amount of faces?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, mirror, mirror-modifier

So for every tutorial I see about created a character that is human like, it always starts with people creating a cube/sphere then cutting it in half and mirroring the other side.

I'm confused when to use a normal cylinder or other solid object because blender already has those pre-made so what would be the benefit of creating the same exact thing but with a mirror?

If my characters shape is a cylinder, is it necessary to make it mirrored on the side or should I just use a normal cylinder?

[image]

For example, if I want to intrude the top like in the picture on the left, when I try it with the mirror cylinder it causes this middle part to be created, which causes uncessary problems.

[image]

So now I am confused because every video course/tutorial always creates the shapes using the mirror modifier, yet I don't know when to use it for character creation or when to not use it.

Like this character here https://www.renderhub.com/medox/pencil-cartoon/pencil-cartoon-01.jpg

Would you create this using mirror modifier or just a simple cylinder? because from my view it looks like one cylinder with more torus or cylinders around it and that's all.

However, I am unsure since I can't find any rules or models to follow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of mirror modifier is to work nearly half the time needed. There are no absolute rules, you can use the workflow you want, but using mirror on symmetric characters is more efficient, expecially with complex tasks, you only need to learn modeling tecniques to deal with every situation. In your example the fast combination of mirror and solidify modifier would get the job done in seconds. I would definively use mirror if I had to model the pencil character in the link, and the cylinders + toruses approach is not considered "correct" as it would lead into problems if animated (and it would waste unnecessary geometry).

So, my personal advice is to follow the tutorials guidance, but nothing is written on stone, an Hybrid approach can be considered too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: how did you intrude perfectly in the center? how come mine made that middle section visible?

Comment: First picure is only made by modifiers (that can be applied to obtain actual geometry. Second picture add a cylinder, delete half, add mirror, add 2 loop cuts, select the face loop and extrude along normals.